How to wrap renderItem in useCallback when using function-as-children pattern
I have created a component FirstChild that offers me a function close with the Function as Children construction, like so.
const Parent = () => {
  return <FirstChild>
    {({ close }) => <FlatList renderItem={(item) => { /* uses 'close' and 'item' */ }} />}
  </FirstChild>
}

Now I want to wrap the closure passed to renderItem in a useCallback. My problem is, when I try to do that, I have no access to the close method. How do I fix this?
I have tried the following:
const Parent = () => {
  return <FirstChild>
    {({ close }) => {
      // Problem: I should not use a hook at this place!
      const renderItem = useCallback((item) => /* uses 'close' and 'item' */, []);
      return <FlatList renderItem={renderItem} />}
  </FirstChild>
}

and
const Parent = () => {
  // Problem: close is not defined here.
  const renderItem = useCallback((item) => /* uses 'close' and 'item' */, []);
  return <FirstChild>
    {({ close }) => <FlatList renderItem={renderItem} />
  </FirstChild>
}

and
const Parent = () => {
  // Problem: This caches the wrong function. RenderItem still contains a closure and FlatList
  // is re-rendered on each rerender of Parent, because the closure is recreated on each
  // render of Parent
  const getRenderItemFunction = useCallback(
    (close) => (item) => /* uses 'close' and 'item' */,
    []
  );

  return <FirstChild>
    {({ close }) => <FlatList renderItem={(item) => getRenderItemFunction(close)(item)} />
  </FirstChild>
}

